# How to fix VIM system clipboard usage in Mountain Lion

Tags: vim

`set clipboard+=unnamed` is one of my favorite *.vimrc* configs. Thanks to it, yanks and deletes are copied to my system clipboard and I can easily paste them to other applications.

However, when I upgraded to Mountain Lion, this setting broke down.

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing also mentions this: *As of Mountain Lion, the previous tip does not appear to work in system-provided vim; yanked lines do not go into the system clipboard, nor does anything yanked to the * or + registers.*

Answer (score 3):

The version of Vim provided by Apple has *always* been lacking useful features, `+clipboard` among them, but also Python and Ruby support or X11-related capabilities.

The solution has *always* been to install an up-to-date Vim yourself. There are many ways to do that. From relatively painless to rather involved:

- Install MacVim and put the bundled `mvim` script in your path. After that `$ mvim filename` will open MacVim and `$ mvim -f filename` will open MacVim's Vim executable in the terminal. Use an alias if you want to keep typing `$ vim filename`.
- Use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).
- [Install from the sources](https://www.vim.org/download.php#unix).