# How to have vim leverage system clipboard in Mountain Lion

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get VIM to access the system clipboard.  As I see it, here are my options:

1. Recompile VIM and specify that access to the clipboard, per [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/235505/compiling-vim-with-xterm-clipboard-support).
2. Install a newer version of VIM using homebrew, per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234837/how-to-fix-vim-system-clipboard-usage-in-mountain-lion).

I'd prefer to do the second option.  Does anyone know if this will actually solve the problem I'm having?  Also, are there other solutions to this copy/paste problem that haven't been listed here?

MY SOLUTION: I ended up installing MacVim and making it the default Vim.  I found [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59375/how-do-i-install-macvim) helpful.  I ran this command:

```
brew install macvim --override-system-vim
```

then modified my .bash_profile and that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using a version of Vim that was not built with clipboard support. *Of course* the solution to this "problem" is to use a version of Vim that is built with clipboard support.

What does `$ vim --version` say?

There are many answers on **SO** describing your options, either related to Ruby or Python support or to clipboard support. The solution is the same every time: install a proper build. Just pick the process you are most comfortable with.

The absolute simplest solution is to install MacVim and use the bundled `mvim` script to run MacVim on the command line. It's totally painless and *guaranteed* to work.

I don't recommend building from the sources as it can be a needlessly frustrating task.

Homebrew and MacPorts are also good options but I don't like all the symlinking that is done in Homebrew's case. YMMV.

You have asked the question more than 17 minutes ago. That's more than enough time to try all your options. Did you actually *try* something?

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response.  My vim version is 7.3.  I'll probably go with MacVim or Homebrew.  Would you care to go into more detail on why you're not a fan of homebrew's habit of symlinking?  Is that an aesthetic decision or are their some sort of performance issues involved?

Comment: Symlinking is both aggressive, rude and fragile. It's aggressive because it overwrites system defaults. It's rude because UNIX and thus Mac OS X, is a multi-user system: *your* changes are not supposed to  cause much trouble to other users. It's fragile because those system defaults may or may not be upgraded by a future system update, which would break your symlinks. Instead, it's better to install your own stuff somewhere else, where it won't interfere with anything and leave the base system as clean as possible.

Comment: MacPorts and Homebrew are OK because they put their stuff in special places and it's up to *you* to configure your environment so that it uses your user-installed programs instead of the default ones. But the Homebrew recipe goes a little too far by symlinking default stuff to its own user-installed stuff. Customizing the user's `*rc` file would be a more sensible approach in my opinion. Installing MacVim manually and adding a couple of lines to your `*rc` is simply the cleanest, fastest and most effective way to install a proper Vim build on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [fakeclip](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2098) plugin.